# Use Ceva's Theorem to calculate $|PC|$

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

Refer to the figure below. The distances are $|AR| = 9, |RB| = 21, |BC| = 40, |CQ| = 18$, and $|QA| = 12$. Use Ceva’s Theorem for this configuration to calculate $|PC|$.

[image]

Curve's Theorem seems pretty straight forward, except I am not given $|BP|$. Here is what I have:

**Attempt**

\begin{align}
\dfrac{AR}{RB}\cdot\dfrac{BP}{PC}\cdot\dfrac{CQ}{QA}=1&\Rightarrow \dfrac{BP}{PC}=\dfrac{252}{162}\\
&\Rightarrow\dfrac{BP}{PC}=\dfrac{14}{9}\\
&\Rightarrow PC=\dfrac{9BP}{14}\qquad(\star).
\end{align}
However, I cannot figure out how to find $BP$. My initial thought is to use the angle bisector theorem as follows:

\begin{align}
\dfrac{BP}{PC}=\dfrac{BA}{CA}&\Rightarrow\dfrac{BP}{PC}=\dfrac{RA+RB}{AQ+QC}\\
&\Rightarrow\dfrac{BP}{PC}=\dfrac{30}{30}\\
&\Rightarrow\dfrac{BP}{PC}=1\\
&\Rightarrow BP=PC.
\end{align}
This now tells us that
\begin{align}
BP&=\dfrac{1}{2}BC\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}40\\
&=20
\end{align}
Substituting this result into $(\star)$ gives
\begin{align}
PC&=\dfrac{(9)(20)}{14}\\
&=12.86
\end{align}
However, I am not sure this is correct. I am hoping someone can confirm correctness or point out where I have made errors.

Cheers

Comment: You forgot about: $BP+PC=BC$

Comment: And you have a mistake: you should make clockwise

Comment: If $BP=PC$ then $BP+PC=BC$ implies $2BP=BC$ which implies $BP=\dfrac{1}{2}BC$ is that not correct? Rather, my question is can I use the Bisector Theorem in this way? Also, I am unclear as to what you mean by "you should make clockwise". Can you clarify this please. Thanks

Comment: you may forgot about clockwise, actually. $BP+PC=BC$, but $PC=9BP/14$, so $BP+PC=23BP/14=BC$

Comment: I mean : are you sure that this lines are bisectors ?

Comment: I am not sure these line are bisectors, so I suppose that means I cannot use the Bisector Theorem, however, I do not know how els to find the length of BP.

Comment: But you have ceva's theorem and you know length of BC

Comment: I see now, set $\dfrac{23BP}{14}=40$ and solve for $BP$. Then take my value for $BP$ and use it to find $PC$.

Comment: yes, that's right